# Erros are not showing in new.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails but I am unable to get any error on invalid form submission. They are only displaying in create controller.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def new
    @user = User.new
end
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
        redirect_to new_user_path
    else
        puts @user.errors.full_messages
        render :new,status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end

private

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username,:email,:password)
end
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
validates :username,:email,:password,presence:true
end
```

and here is my new.erb.html code

```
 <%=form_with model: @user do |form| %>
    <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div>
        <h2><%=pluralize(@user.errors.count,"Error")%></h2>
        <ul>
            <%@user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|%>
                <li><%=msg%></li>
            <%end%>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <%=form.label :username , "Username"%>
    <%=form.text_field :username%>
    <%=form.label :email,"Email"%>
    <%=form.text_field :email%>
    <%=form.label :password,"Password"%>
    <%=form.password_field :password%>
    <%=form.submit%>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by providing local:true option to form_with.
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28764